# Android SDK - Install Intel HAXM

Tags: finder, install, android

I've just been looking at updating my SDK install for Android with the Intel Atom images and the x86 emulator using [these](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/configuring_the_x86_emulator/) instructions:

I've gotten to step 3 but I have so far completely failed to locate this file and run the .dmg to install it.

Looking at the path where the SDK is installed it says the SDK is here:

```
/Users/<name>/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-mac-x86
```

But Finder won't let me in to my own Library folder (assuming this is where the .dmg is.  How do I get in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In finder in the top menu bar:

- Click **Go**
- **Press** and **hold** the <kbd>shift</kbd>-button on your keyboard
- **Library** will show up, and you can click it.